# Clear remembered passwords in `Team Explorer` pane in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, passwords, remember-me, team-explorer

Every time I open `Team Explorer` pane in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, it automatically log in with some certain remembered account which I don't want to.

I'm looking for way to remove the remembered stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Team Explorer uses standard Windows authentication techniques to authenticate to Team Foundation Server.  If there are Windows Credentials stored in Credential Manager, it will use those to authenticate.  If not, it will use your domain credentials.

So, check Credential Manager:  Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager.  If there are Windows Credentials stored there for your TFS server, removing them will begin authenticating you with your logged-in credentials.  If you want to override this behavior, add new credentials there.

Comment: I've checked and the passwords stored there. I notice that the account stored without saying any thing related to TFS or VS2010

Comment: I am connecting to a TFS server that authenticates against a different domain. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!